# How to run a command line in txt file from Jupyter Notebook (python 3.8) and get output?

Tags: python, image-processing, cmd, jupyter-notebook, command

I'm using Jupyter Notebook and python 3.8.
Depending on other variables, I will generate a txt file with the command that must be entered (literally) on the command line. For example: *topup --imain potato*. 
This command is in the txt file as a line. I want to run this command as if in the cmd. I also want to do all of this from Jupyter Notebook and have some output to know what is going on.

Is it possible? 
I also accept other ways to do this (I'm trying to automate an FSL procedure).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling an external command from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-from-python)

Comment: This might also be helpful for other people: > cmd= 'python '+'"'+main+sep+'run_py.txt'+'"'
>lasito=subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True) >out, err = lasito.communicate()